# Make sure that such a field combination exists in another table when inserting

Tags: postgresql, schema, constraint

Table A:

```
id | name | user_id
```

Table B:

```
id | type
```

Table A_B

```
id | table_a_id | table_b_id | user_id
```

Table A_B is a standard linking table for a many-to-many relationship except that probably using a surrogate key is unnecessary here.

What I also want to achieve is that inserting a row into `Table A_B` is impossible if there is no such `(id, user_id)` combination in `Table_A`.

Of course, I have foreign keys for `table_a_id` and `table_b_id` but that only guarantees that there are matching entries in the corresponding tables.
I also added a UNIQUE constraint on `(table_a_id, table_b_id, user_id)` but again this doesn't prevent from inserting a row that shouldn't be inserted.

What is the best way to achieve this behavior? So far the only feasible option I can think of is checking the condition programmatically by selecting from `Table_A` first, which doesn't however seem smart.

What are some other options?

EDIT:
One idea based on the comments (`user_id` is removed from the junction table schema)

```
        INSERT INTO a_b
            (
              table_a_id,
              table_b_id
            )
            SELECT id, user_id, <input_table_b_id>
            FROM table_a
            WHERE id = <input_table_a_id> AND user_id = <input_user_id>
```

Comment: If you want any combination of `(table_a_id, user_id)` you add to table `a_b` to have a relevant row  `(id, user_id)` in table `a` then you need to add a FOREIGN KEY like that.  `CONSTRAINT a_b__ref__a__fk FOREIGN KEY (table_a_id, user_id) REFERENCES a (id, user_id)` - and the required UNIQUE constraint on table `a`

Comment: This makes sense, but it feels a bit awkward to create a UNIQUE constraint on `(id, user_id)` given that `id` is already unique. Or isn't that a bad practice?

Comment: It's denormalization, yes. The other option is to remove user_if from table a_b. You can always get this info with a join.

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ, see my edit, please. Do you think this approach looks better? It's a bit hacky too but at least this way the query itself guarantees that we only consider an existing match from `table_a` to be inserted

Answer (score 2):

> What I also want to achieve is that inserting a row into Table A_B is impossible if there is no such (id, user_id) combination in Table_A.

Am I misunderstanding something or did you not consider

```
FOREIGN KEY (table_a_id, userId) REFERENCES Table_A(id, userId)
```